# Unhandle Promise sequelize hooks and encrypt password

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, hook

I'm tryng to register a user in my database.

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const { Model, DataTypes } = sequelize
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

class User extends Model {

  isPasswordValid(encondedPassword, password) {
   return bcrypt.compareSync(password, encondedPassword)
  }

  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      } 
    }, {
      hooks: {
          beforeCreate:  (user, options) => {
            const salt =  bcrypt.genSaltSync()
            user.setAttributes('password', bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt))
          }
      },
      sequelize
    })
  }
}

module.exports = User
```

But when I call User.create({email, password}) it gives me and error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: null value in column "password" violates not-null constraint .

If a delete my hook the code works fine but the password will not be encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setAttributes` [receive 3 arguments or an object](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/4d9165b6cc11517a023e10eb30e27094dc0f46e1/types/lib/model.d.ts#L2569-L2570)

Try this

```
user.setAttributes('setAttributes', 'password', bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt))
//OR
user.setAttributes({password: bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt)})
```

Simpler use [`setDataValue`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-setDataValue)

```
user.setDataValue('password', bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt))
```

Comment: it worked. Also, using user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt) worked as well

Comment: Yes, the issue is the way you called `setAttributes`